# Extremum of a function that is neither a critical point nor a stationary point? ( Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

What I have in mind while asking this question is : are " extrema" , " critical point" and " stationary point" 3 overlapping ***but distinct*** concepts ( taken in extension) ?

- I have no doubt that not all critical points are stationary points ( example $f(0)$ with $f(x)= |x|$)  and not all critical points are extrema
- I have no doubt that not all stationary points are critical points ( example $f(0)$ with $f(x)= x^3$ ) and not all stationary points are extrema
- but I'd like to be sure that not all extrema are critical points or stationary points.

---

I wonder whether the following sentence is correct: " it is possible for a continuous function to have extrema that are ***neither*** critical points ***nor*** stationary points".

Is the following an example : $(2,f(2))$ and $(4,f(4))$ with  $f$ defined on the closed interval $[2,4]$  by $f(x) = x^2$?

Saying that these points are neither critical points nor stationary means that the derivative exists at $x=2$ and $x=4$ ( unless they'd be critical points) and that the derivative is not zero at these points ( unless they'd be stationary) .

But is this possible whitout a two sided limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto|x|$.

**Theorem.**
Let $f:I\subset\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $x_0\in I^\circ$ an interior local extrema. Then either $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$ or $f'(x_0)=0$.

*Proof.* Assume $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and w.l.o.g. $x_0$ is a local minimum. For $h>0$ small enough we have $f(x_0+h)\geq f(x_0)$, therefore
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h \geq 0.
$$
Similarly, considering $h<0$ small enough in absolute value, we get
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h \leq 0.
$$
Therefore it must be $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: do you mean the point $(0, f(0))$ ? This is a critical point , isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is an interior extrema, but it is not stationary because $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Oh wait, now that i thing of it, in some contexts people call points of non-differentiability *critical points*. In this sense my example does not qualify because you would consider $0$ to be critical. If this the case, then the answer is negative: interior extrema must be critical points in this sense (either non differentiable, or the derivative exists and is $0$).

Comment: @Fredrico What is the proof of that ?

Comment: I edited the answer. It's the most basic theorem in this context. Surely you must have encountered it if you are studying this subject.

Comment: @Fredrico yes but that’s what the question is asking .

Comment: Do I understand correctly your answer if I translate it as : " unless an extremum is located at an endpoint of a closed interval, it must be either a critical point or a point at which the derivative is equal to $0$" ?

Comment: Yes, if you have an interior local extremum, either the function is not differentiable there (possibly not even continuous), or the derivative exists and is $0$.